# vb.net Split Text file into different files by section

Tags: vb.net

I have a lot of text files that have the same structure

They each have an unknown number of sections

All sections names are known. They are stored as an Array.

```
Dim alpha() As String = {"Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3"}
```

The sections are just plain text without any symbol to help identify. But the text below them has all kinds of symbols and text.

:
ex.

**Section 1**

There is a lot of text with symbols and numbers and newLines.

**Section 2**

There is a lot of text with symbols and numbers and newLines.

**Section 3**

There is a lot of text with symbols and numbers and newLines.

Now. There is no way to get this with regex cause each section is different and can't match with anything.
I want to save each section into a different file. If you can help me to figure out how to get, maybe, an array for each section for each different file i can do the saving part.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please add an example of the text file and how do you want it to be splitted - into lines, words ,etc.

Comment: Thats any example abode. An know title and then an unknow number of lines that have unknow text.

Comment: Post the text with the symbols so we can know what delimiters to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, Stackoverflow isnt a code writing service, but I couldn't resist

The code below will do what you ask.

```
Dim fn As String = "K:\sectiontest.txt"
Dim completeFile As String()
Dim sectionsPostSplitting As String()()

Private Function GetSectionIndexes() As List(Of Integer)
    Dim SectionIndexes As New List(Of Integer)
    For i As Integer = 0 To completeFile.Count - 1
        If completeFile(i).StartsWith("Section") Then
            SectionIndexes.Add(i)
        End If
    Next
    Return SectionIndexes
End Function

Private Function GetSectionText(i As Integer, temptxtarray As String()) As String()
    Dim sectionText As New List(Of String)
    Dim j As Integer = i
    j += 1
    While (j < temptxtarray.Length - 1) And (Not temptxtarray(j).StartsWith("Section"))
        sectionText.Add(temptxtarray(j))
        j += 1
    End While
    Return sectionText.ToArray
End Function

Private Function SplitCompleteText(txt As String()) As String()()
    Dim sectionsText As New List(Of String())
    Dim sectionIndexes As List(Of Integer) = GetSectionIndexes()
    For i As Integer = 0 To sectionIndexes.Count - 1
        sectionsText.Add(GetSectionText(sectionIndexes(i), completeFile))
    Next
    Return sectionsText.ToArray
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    completeFile = File.ReadAllLines(fn)
    sectionsPostSplitting = SplitCompleteText(completeFile)
End Sub
```

The line..

```
sectionsPostSplitting = SplitCompleteText(completeFile)
```

in the button.click event handler will leave you with an array with each item in the array being an array of strings equalling the text from each section without the section header. So `sectionsPostSplitting(0)` will be an array of one line strings for section 1 and so on.